# Как получить headers из входящего запроса php

Tags: php, http, header

Я хочу получить строку authorization из входящего запроса php (php://input)
Пробовал использовать функцию

```
get_headers('php://input');
```

Но получил ошибку

> get_headers(): This function may only be used against URLs in /path..

Искал в православных и не только интернетах... но не нашёл никакую информацию на этот счёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$headers = getallheaders();
var_dump($headers['Content-Name']);
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26462884/15331960

Answer (score 1):

Все в инете есть, если я что не путаю:

```
<?php
    $headers = apache_request_headers();    
    foreach ($headers as $header => $value) {
        echo "$header: $value <br>\n";
    }
    ?>
```

А для get_headers нужен целевой url

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com';
print_r(get_headers($url));
print_r(get_headers($url, 1));
?>
```

Comment: Это не работает с php://input

Comment: Я что-то не пойму - строку авторизации - может быть, вам нужен глобальный post или get, а не header, откуда строка взялась php://input?

Answer (score 1):

Сам только что искал как можно получить Headers входящего запроса, оказалось ничего сложного, существуют два аналогичных метода:

- `getallheaders()`
- `apache_request_headers()`

Возвращают `array` **ключ=значение**

Answer (score 0):

[Переменная $_SERVER - это массив, содержащий информацию, такую как **заголовки**, пути и местоположения скриптов.](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php)